# Ejecutar un Javascript desde code-behind .net 4.5

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, webservice

Estoy desarrollando un proceso de gestión a una base de datos desde un webservice y ya que el proceso tarda más de 20 minutos necesito que muestre al usuario mensajes en un `<textarea>` en una parte de la pagina, **sin actualizar la pagina** para esto coloque un javascript en la pagina que cuando se ejecuta agrega una línea de texto (la cual le paso por parámetro) a dicho `<textarea>` desde un `EventListener` que escucha los eventos que genero desde el código que se encarga de hacer la gestión cada vez que quiero mostrar un mensaje en pantalla.

El problema es que el Javascript nunca se me ejecuta, y lo estoy llamando así:
`ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"mandarmensaje", "Feed(\'" + sender.ToString() + "\');", true);`

Ya probe el javascript ejecutando desde un botón y si funciona bien y cuando debugueo el comando se "ejecuta" sin error pero no hace nada, y pongo `alert();` dentro del script a ver si al menos entra y tampoco.

El **Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function Feed(msg) {
       msg.replace(/@/g, "\r");         
       document.getElementById("feedbackText").value = document.getElementById("feedbackText").value + "\r" + msg;
    }  
</script>
```

> El replace es porque le paso saltos de linea como "@" y ahi los vuelvo a convertir, para no tener problemas con el interpretador web.

Llevo 2 dias en esto, gracias al que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: El **Javascript**

         `<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         function Feed(msg) {
         msg.replace(/@/g, "\r");
         document.getElementById("feedbackText").value = 
        document.getElementById("feedbackText").value + "\r" + msg;
         }
        </script>`

El replace es porque le paso saltos de linea como "@" y ahi los vuelvo a convertir, para no tener problemas con el interpretador web.

Comment: ¿Te muestra algún error la consola de tu explorador? ¿El valor de `sender.ToString()` no tendrá comillas simples?. Sabes que al usar `RegisterStartupScript` la key debería ser única, por ende es bueno relacionarlo con un [`Guid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.guid.newguid(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Davilo no me sale ningun error, y si tiene las comillas simples de hecho ahora se las paso como \' para evitar problemas segun esto que lei al respecto https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/ No entiendo lo que me dices del key que debe de ser unico, eso es lo unico que yo ejecuto utilizando `RegisterStartupScript`, como implemento eso de la Guid?

Comment: Para hacer la prueba, cambia por `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "console.log('Hi!');", true);` y revisa si en la consola te sale el mensaje _Hi!_.

Comment: @davilo Ya solucione, me ayudaste a darme cuenta, el problema es que cuando se ejecutaba mi `EventListener` lo hacia muchas veces y yo pensaba que era un error y puse una condición al inicio para que suprimiera las repeticiones iguales y resulta que en realidad el código entra como en un ciclo infinito hasta que se atiende bien.
 Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que alcanzo a entender, realizas un proceso en el servidor que tarda algún tiempo y necesita ejecutar un JavaScript en el cliente, evitando el `postback`.

Yo lo hago así:

Coloco un *script* en la pagina ASPX por ejemplo, que corre en el servidor y le coloco la etiqueta `runat=server` y en esa misma página coloco un *script* que se ejecuta en el lado del cliente.

De esa forma la función en el servidor le da la orden de ejecutarse a la del lado del navegador.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este código funciona así, (para dar mas claridad) al cargar la página el evento `Page_load` organiza que cuando el usuario haga clic en el botón `Procesar`, se ejecutan dos procesos simultáneamente, uno en el servidor que realiza consultas larga a una base de datos y como toma un rato largo, el otro evento (el que registro `Page_load`) ejecuta el *script* en el lado del cliente que muestra una animación que le indica al usuario que debe esperar.

Este es el código:

```
<%--Codigo JavaScript--%>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnAceptar.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "javascript:return fnAceptar();");
    }
</script>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function fnAceptar() {
        alert('El Contenido del TextBox es: ' + document.getElementById("txtNombre").value);
        document.getElementById("txtNombre").value = '';
    }
</script>
```

Este [link](http://www.maestrosdelweb.com/tutorial-asp-net-ejecutar-codigo-javascript-en-aspnet/) quizás le sea útil.

Comment: Exactamente escribo con el javascript para evitar que me haga postback la pagina.

Pero no entiendo algo en tu solucion, tu me dices que escriba dos script, al primero lo ponga como `runat="server"` y lo llamo a ejecutarse desde mi code-behind y luego este cuando se ejecute llame al segundo script que no tiene el `runat="server"` y este me escriba del lado del cliente lo que yo quiero?

Comment: Si esa es la idea. El problema con el code-behind es que al hacer algo se produce el postback. Con esta solución, se ejecuta el script en el cliente a pesar del postback.

Comment: Excelente. Pero ahora te explico, yo ejecuto mi proceso de DB en una clase estática y no desde el code-behind de la pagina web, mi code-behind tiene es un `EventListener` que ejecuta mi JavaScript cada vez que se activa. Como yo llamo desde ese `EventListener` ese script que me dices tu coloque en el lado del servidor? hago que el `EventListener` sea mi script?

Comment: @Jesus Hergueta. Creo que quizás para este caso en particular no sea la mejor solución la que usted plantea. Quizas cambiando el enfoque de la solución. Yo le sugiero respetuosamente que examine la opción de hacerlo con Ajax de Jquery,  Tal vez si es el javascript en el cliente quien llama a un método o servicio en el servidor y le pide cuentas del proceso cada cierto tiempo para mostrar el resultado parcial hasta finalizar. Yo solía hacerlo de esa forma, usando C# y Jquery.

Comment: Veras que lo pensé bastante, pero el costo en tiempo iba a ser muy fuerte asi que intente insistir. A final de cuentas el problema es que cuando se ejecutaba mi EventListener lo hacia muchas veces y yo pensaba que era un error y puse una condición al inicio para que suprimiera las repeticiones iguales y resulta que en realidad el código entra como en un ciclo infinito hasta que se atiende bien.

De igual manera gracias, tu enfoque me dio ideas para otras soluciones anteriores que me he quedado estancado de parecidas maneras.

Muchas Gracias!.

Comment: Los fragmentos de código o Snippets solo funcionan para Javascript, HTML y CSS. Cualquier otro lenguaje no está contemplado.